# What is a good asynchronous file sharing application?

Tags: file-sharing

I am looking for a file sharing application for this scenario:

I want to share a file with a remote computer (on LAN or WAN) and if this computer is offline, I want the application to wait until the remote computer comes online, share the file and notify the user on the remote computer.

I need this application mostly for a local area network between two computers. So I don't want to use services like Dropbox, Syncplicity, eg. as they duplicate the data on their servers, and this would not be good for my bandwith.

Basically, what I want is an extended version of file sharing with these features:

- Notification of shared files.
- Queueing of file sharing jobs if the remote computer is offline and sharing the files when it comes online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft Live Sync](http://sync.live.com/) does p2p file transfer.